# output issue with pdo::fetchall

Tags: php, pdo

source code:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=oop;host=localhost;';
$user = 'admin';
$password = 'password';
try {
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e)
{
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from be_users");
$stmt->execute();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => tom
            [0] => tom
            [email] => dsfde@gmail.com
            [1] => dsfde@gmail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => tom3
            [0] => tom3
            [email] => sdfsdfs@gmail.com
            [1] => sdfsdfs@gmail.com
        )
     ...
```

Question:

Why the result is not like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [username] => tom
            [email] => dsfde@gmail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [username] => tom3
            [email] => sdfsdfs@gmail.com
              )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the default fetch style, which is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, meaning that you will get an array indexed both numerical and associative. Use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead:

```
print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

You'll find more information about fetch styles in the manual page of [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Note that you can specify the fetch mode per statement or globally per `PDO` instance:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=oop;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $opt);
```

note the fetch mode

Answer (score 0):

You have to manualy specify the fetch style:

```
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```